# python with open and for loop through a .txt file

Tags: python-2.7

**New to python and have not found question for this kind of code. 
I'm trying to read one line at a time from another text(infile) file and the cmd gives me "syntax error" when it reaches line 2.

What have I missed?**

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as infile:
    lines = []
    for line in infile:
        lines.append(line)

while lines:
    print len(lines), ':', lines.pop(),
```

Comment: well, you misspelled `infile` as `inflile` in your 2nd line

Comment: sry ill fix it, accidental when I edited text here. Thanks

Comment: You should not use `with`, if you do not know why you are using it. Do you know why?

Comment: By "first line", do you mean the "import sys" line?  That would suggest your program is being interpreted by something other than Python.

Comment: We are recommended to use 'with' for filestream handling to execute open command and for assigning to var. Need the filestream to close auto when code block exits. 

Any other similar ways you recommend ? :)

Comment: @brycem No, the other file not the code.

Comment: Maybe I'm typing wrong commands in cmd? (I'm quite new to coding and python of course)

Comment: @YungDev, I still don't understand on what line of your program you're encountering the error.  Are you invoking your program with the command "python" followed by the name of your program?

Comment: @brycem it jumps to line 2 and gives error on line 2. The .txt file consist of random text.

Comment: @YungDev when I run your program it works perfectly.  Could you have hidden control characters in your original source code?

Comment: @brycem hmm strange, nothing else in code. What do you write in cmd if I may ask ?

Comment: @YungDev I use "python program.py params"

Comment: dear @brycem thanks! I changed sys.argv[] to 'mytextfile.txt' and it works BUT, my main goal is to get it working directly in cmd. If I'm not mistaken it should work?

Comment: @YungDev I believe it should work.  My last guess is that the 'sys' module being found is incorrect somehow.  Do you have a stray 'sys.py' in your project somewhere, perhaps?

Comment: @brycem dude you save me time, thanks again. 
I changed the sys.argv to .txt file and it works and I changed back to give it a try 'manually' n cmd and now its not giving error anymore.